# Horizontal Floating Bar position below header

Tags: css

I'm using activecampaign for my form. I need it to go below my header. The prpblem is, it is a floating bar which only goes on top or bottom. How do I posistion it jist below the header? Thanks!!!

Comment: Could you put your code out for us to see. Hard to judge if we cant see what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other info this is my best guess at what you are trying to do... Correct me if I am wrong.

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #CCC;
}

#formBox {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  bottom: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}

#bodyStuff {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightBlue;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"><h1>HEADER</h1>

  <div id="formBox">FORM<br>
    <input type="text"><br>
     <input type="text"><br><hr>
     <input type="submit">
  </div>

</div>

<div id="bodyStuff">BODY</div>
```